How to simplify import statements when adding a package with a src layout as a submodule in Python?
I have a Python package, superpackage, with a src layout, and I'm trying to add another package, pack1, also with a src layout, as a submodule. Both are git directories.
My goal is to streamline the import statements so that I can import module1 directly from superpackage.pack1 without specifying the entire path.
Here's the basic structure of my superpackage:
superpackage/
├── .git/
├── src/
│   └── superpackage/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── pack1/      # submodule pointing to pack1 repository
├── setup.cfg
└── pyproject.toml

And the structure of pack1:
pack1/
├── .git/
├── src/
│   └── pack1/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module1.py

I added pack1 as a submodule to superpackage with the following commands:
cd superpackage
git submodule add ../pack1 src/superpackage/pack1
git commit -am "Added pack1 as submodules"

Currently, to access module1, I need to use a lengthy import statement:
from superpackage.pack1.src.pack1 import module1

However, what i want to do is :
from superpackage.pack1 import module1


The only solution I found involves adding an __init__.py file in src/pack1 with the following line:
from .src.pack1 import module1

However, this solution seems not very versatile and requires modifications for each module. I'm also concerned about the potential impacts on the submodule.
How can I achieve the desired import behavior ? Is there another way ?


Is there a specific reason why you made pack1 a submodule instead of a package by itself which you can then install into the superpackage's environment?

For your current setup, you're solution in __init__.py is the way to go.

I have a main toolbox package with different folders that grew quite a lot, i want to be able to separate the some of the folders as independent packages so that i can use them individually in different projects without having to incorporate the whole original package when i only need a tiny part but still conserve the same import to not break project that use the main package

This is a common problem, of conflating repository layout with package layout. Don't try to execute your code directly from the source repository; install it (to a virtual environment, for example) first. src should never appear as a package name in your code; go from there.

Check out pip's editable installs that allows you to install a package and make changes to it. Useful for when you're working on multiple packages at once.

@chepner, well it's more a byproduct of using submodule to integrate a package into anotherone...

@DMalan, Thank you
May be i wasn't describing it very well the main point is to break a quite big package with several submodules into several subpackages that can live on there own, without breaking the compatibility of the programs using the original big package. Thus keeping the subpackages integrated into the big package and being able to push and pull from the big package.

Yes, and I'm saying that your current repository layout cannot double as a definition of a Python package.

The point of the src layout is that you can not import as-is. Import packages and modules need to be installed properly first. And editable installation helps during the development phase (no need to re-install after each code modification). -- Or maybe what you are after is namespace packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

To solve the import path issue, I decided to use Python's namespace packages feature as mentioned by @sinoroc. This feature allows multiple directories to collectively serve as a single Python package
I modified pack1's setup.cfg to declare it as a namespace package. Here's how the setup.cfg looks:
[metadata]
name = superpackage-pack1
version = 0.1.0

[options]
package_dir =
    =src
packages = find_namespace:

[options.packages.find]
where = src

The structure became :
superpackage/
├── .git/
├── src/
│   └── superpackage/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── module.py
├── setup.cfg
└── pyproject.toml

And the structure of pack1:
pack1/
├── .git/
├── src/
│   └── superpackage/
│       └── pack1/
│            ├── __init__.py
│            └── module1.py

It allows to distribute pack1 as a single entity and  can still maintain previous use of pack1:
from superpackage.pack1 import module1

but not as single entity :
from pack1 import module1 

unless i modify the setup.cfg
It also has the drawback of forcing to install all sub-packages like pack1 independently but that's fine i guess
